# Setting `egress-settings=all` won't let my function call external APIs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to restrict access to some APIs setting the flag `--ingress-settings internal-only` when deployed.

I'd expect that when I set all egress traffic from another function to `--egress-settings all`, this function would still be able to call external APIs.

```
# Deploy for restricted access http-function
gcloud functions deploy $FUNCTION_NAME \
  --runtime nodejs12 \
  --memory 256MB \
  --timeout 30s \
  --trigger-http \
  --allow-unauthenticated \
  --ingress-settings internal-only \
  --egress-settings all \
  --vpc-connector $VPC_CONNECTOR
```

```
# Deploy for function invoking the previous one internally
gcloud functions deploy vitals-data-ms-test \
  --source src/test \
  --env-vars-file .env.live.yaml \
  --runtime nodejs12 \
  --memory 128MB \
  --timeout 30s \
  --trigger-resource vitals-data-bigquery \
  --trigger-event providers/cloud.pubsub/eventTypes/topic.publish \
  --egress-settings all \
  --vpc-connector $VPC_CONNECTOR
```

Comment: Do you have an error? a timeout?

Comment: Yes the cloud function timesout when making an external request.

Answer (score 0):

I created a Cloud NAT associated with my VPC and boom! Issue solved.

[image]